# angular 5 background image not binding some android Devices?

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular5, background-image

I am using **ionic3** and **angular5** background image not binding on some android devices. I have tried the following techniques to bind background image.

```
   <!-- Solution 1 -->
  <ion-slides #bannerSlider *ngIf="banners.length">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let banner of banners"
                [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : 'url(' + banner.banner_image?.url + ')'}">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>

 <!-- Solution 2 -->
  <ion-slides #bannerSlider *ngIf="banners.length">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let banner of banners"
                [style.background-image]="'url(' + banner.banner_image?.url+ ')'">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<ion-slides #bannerSlider *ngIf="banners.length">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let banner of banners"
            [style.background]="'url(' + banner.banner_image?.url+ ')'">
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Comment: Thank you @Pradnya Sinalkar i have tried it's not working.

Comment: Can you specify browser version and android version?

Comment: Android Version 4.4.2.  it's hybrid mobile app so browser not needed.

Comment: If you do more research, you will find, Ionic3 and its all component and directives works well with Android 4.4.4 and above version. Maybe *ngStyle and *ngClass which updated with latest angular and Ionic framework will not work in your case.

Comment: Thank you @Pradnya Sinalkar. I have researched a lot of things regarding this issue finally I conclude with your solution. once again thank you for your valuable time to spend for me.

Comment: This link will guide you. Visit https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/minimum-android-version-supported-by-ionicv2/54164/7. All is about android version(most is 4.4.4 and above) and it's support.